# An Error message, says "Error while processing samples" which occurs while generating Dashboard from Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am using JMeter 5.4.1 for load testing, I wanted to generate a reporting dashboard from a .jtl file.

When I run the following command from Command Prompt:

```
jmeter -g E:\Outcode\ProtocolNow\Data\Jmeterlog\scriptresults.jtl -f -o E:\Outcode\ProtocolNow\Data\Jmeterlog\HTMLRESULTS
```

Error on Command Prompt:

```
An error occurred: Error while processing samples: Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Begin size 1 is not equal to fixed size 5
errorlevel=1
```

I am not able to figure out the reason.

First 3 lines from the .jtl log are posted below:

```
timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,failureMessage,bytes,sentBytes,grpThreads,allThreads,URL,Latency,IdleTime,Connect
1637132376961,1932,oauth/token,200,OK,jp@gc - Ultimate Thread Group 1-10,text,true,,1955,541,2,2,https://app.ex.com/oauth/token,1931,0,1306
1637132377905,1450,oauth/token,200,OK,jp@gc - Ultimate Thread Group 1-9,text,true,,1693,561,3,3,https://app.ex.com/oauth/token,1450,0,862
1637132379774,353,Login/SetDefaultOrganization,200,OK,jp@gc - Ultimate Thread Group 1-10,text,true,,524,653,4,4,https://app.ex.com/api/Login/SetDefaultOrganization,352,0,0
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using too new JDK version

[image]

As per [Introducing JMeter 5.4: New Features and Abilities](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-jmeter5-4-new-features-and-abilities) you need to use [JDK 8](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/) so you will need to downgrade in order to be able to generate the reporting dashboard.

There is a chance that the issue is fixed in [JMeter nightly build](https://jmeter.apache.org/nightly.html).

Comment: yeah i downgraded the java version and it is working now.